# ListView select on drag Windows 8

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

i have a next question, i have a listview:

Single selection and Tap enabled, which allows to select only one item and selection is done via right mouse click, **but on tablets it should be done with little drag ( like start ) - what property should i add?**

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="OpportunityManagementList" SelectionMode="Single" IsTapEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, by changing the list view teplate - by changing HorizontalScrollMode to HorizontalScrollMode="Auto", here is the complete solution and the behavior is just like Start Menu:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:FieldModifier="public" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single"  CanDragItems="False" ManipulationMode="System" Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" SelectionChanged="CustomerResearchList_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                    <ContentThemeTransition/>
                    <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                    <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" IsZoomChainingEnabled="False" IsZoomInertiaEnabled="False" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <ItemsPresenter HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`IsSwipeEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.isswipeenabled.aspx) should be the one, but that should be enabled by default. If the behavior is not as expected- try switching your `ListView` into a `GridView`.

Comment: Thanks, i will test that when i'll get my hands on a tablet

Comment: You can use the emulator for that.